# sleep, hibernate, hung process problems

Tags: boot, network-manager, suspend, fancontrol

I am running Ubuntu 18.04, on a System 76 laptop, including the standard System 76 video drivers. A while back I made many upgrades over the course of a couple days. Everything from video drivers to a version upgrade to a custom TensorFlow build (and many more, too numerous to mention). Since then, the machine has been exhibiting odd behavior with all of the following:

- the system will not sleep or hibernate or shutdown normally. to shut it down I have to issue the command, 'sudo shutdown now' and then it hibernates, and then I have wake it, and then it shuts down.
- If I try and hibernate or sleep it complains that process is already in process, even though it's never been issued. On this point, I suspect that's why the behavior of the previous point, the shutdown command is killing a hung sleep/hibernate process and hibernating before it can shut down. Waking it clears that process and then it shuts down.
- the machine will automatically hibernate if I issue a 'sudo killall sleep' command, which supports the idea that there is a hung sleep or hibernate process, but it does so when sleep and hibernate were never invoked. However, when waking from that procedure, the graphics are a jumbled mess and I have to reboot to fix it.
- every time it is rebooted, 'bin/sh' now asks for root password or it will not start.
- processes that should start automatically at startup, do not. For example, apache server will not start (there is an error message in the console during boot, "cannot start apache" and I have to start it (and others) manually.
- the network manager will not start (or is hung) at boot, and I have to start it manually "systemctl restart network-manager"
- the fan is always running 24/7, and sometimes on high for hours at a time. When checking temperature readings, all readings are 'na'

All these issues started at once and appear to be related to boot problems where something is hung and/or blocking processes from starting. I realize this is not a lot to go on, but it's all I have and it's all related in that it all started at the same time after upgrades. The computer is usable with a lot or work-arounds, but really annoying.

Any ideas?